# FB user button onClick event attend

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have a custom button on my website and I'm trying to make him a FB event trigger so the user can directly connect to my FB event from external website. I've created an App and just can't figure out how to do it properly.

I can't find any JS SDK API function to achieve that, here is my JS code, please help!

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
        appId      : '#######',
        xfbml      : true,
        version    : 'v2.7'
    }); 

    $('.btn-fb').click(function () { 
        //it should work like that: after click the user logs into FB and subsribe to specific event     
        FB.login(function(){}, {scope: 'publish_actions'});

    });
  };

  // Load the SDK Asynchronously
  (function (d) {
      var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) { return; }
      js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
      js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
      ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
  } (document));
});
```

When I try to call this 'attening' function it only gets my a list off attending users, it should work like that:
button click -> FB login window -> user is attended to event :)

```
FB.api('/EVENT_ID/attending', function(response){
     console.log(response);
});
```

Comment: Thanks :), but I have one thing missing - How to merge /EVENT_ID/attending code with login code to have the rsvp_event permission set ?

Comment: @luschn I am trying to add an user to the event but the code is retrieving the list of attending users:

`FB.login(function(){
              FB.api('/EVENT_ID/attending', function(response){
                console.log(response);
              });
            }, {scope: 'rsvp_event'}); `

How it can be done ?

Comment: this is the working code, problem solved :)

`FB.login(function(){
              FB.api('/EVENT_ID/attending',"POST", function(r){
                console.log("rsvp", r);
              });
            }, {scope: 'rsvp_event'});`

Comment: you should also check if the user really authorized the rsvp_event permission...see this example, with the return_scope parameter: http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-javascript-sdk-login/